# Как убрать из вывода UNREACHABLE хосты

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook, ansible-galaxy

У меня есть hosts файл со статическим инвентарем. В этом файле есть группы хостов, их довольно много, но часть из них в N времени офлайн, часть в онлайн. Когда я выполняю плейбук, мне сыпется огромное колл-во сообщений об анричибл хостах. Как можно убрать из вывода эти хосты?
Пробовал `ignore_unreachable:` True и условие `when: (ansible_facts['status'] == "enabled"` но как и ожидалось, хосты игнорируются, но информационные сообщения все равно сыпятся в консоль.

Comment: Ну а перед выполнением плейбука ты можешь чё-нить выпонить?

Comment: В каком плане ?

Comment: Ну в плане сначала опросить хосты, которые подняты каким-нить nmap'ом и записать их в новый инвентори.

Comment: Так можно конечно, и я впринципе задумывался над тем чтобы создать роль в ансибл, которая и будет сначала опрашивать хосты, а потом подкармливать их

Comment: Ну я просто тоже погуглил и всё что смог найти - это `dynamic inventory`. Так что в общем-то пребилд - вполне себе штатная архитектура.